# Python PIL Image.save() error in case of EPS format

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am trying to convert jpeg files to eps ones. I am using the following code:

```
fp=open("test.jpg",'rb')
im=Image.open(fp)
outf=open('test2.eps','wb')
im.save(outf, 'EPS')
```

However, I ma getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "im2eps2.py", line 11, in <module> im.save(outf, 'EPS')
File "C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 1465, in save
save_handler(self, fp, filename)
File "C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\PIL\EpsImagePlugin.py", line 353, in _save
fp = io.TextIOWrapper(NoCloseStream(fp), encoding='latin-1')
File "C:\Python26\Lib\io.py", line 1429, in __init__
self._seekable = self._telling = self.buffer.seekable()
File "C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\PIL\EpsImagePlugin.py", line 348, in __getattr__
return getattr(self.fp, name)
AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'seekable'
```

I shall be thankful for suggestions.
Thanks

PS: I reinstall PIL from its main page i.e. http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/ and it worked :) Earlier, I used windows installer provided by http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs. I think the problem was with the binary that I installed earlier. Currently, I have 1.1.7 PIL and it is working fine.

Thanks

Comment: I could run your minimal code example without problems.  Maybe there's something else involved in your situation?  Maybe the `outf` isn't a real file or similar?

Comment: I am not able to find the problem in my environment. i even printed type(outf) to be sure and it is indeed <type 'file'>. So, outf is type file. any other clues?

Comment: Well, might be a Windows issue.  I'm testing on Linux, so maybe you just found a bug in the Windows implementation.  Can't help you there, sorry.  But you made sure that the minimal example of the four lines of code you printed above really already shows the problem?  I'm talking about exactly those four lines (and additional import statements), nothing else around.  Those already show the problem on your computer?

Comment: Yes, those are the only lines (apart from import statements).

Comment: Since I'm pretty sure that there are no errors in these four lines of code, I propose to escalate that question to the developers of the Windows version of the PIL module for EPS.  It still might be a misuse, but it pretty much looks like a bug.

Comment: @Alfe thank you very much. i will contact developers then.

Comment: Hi Alfe, it is working now (see my edited post).

Comment: This bug was fixed in Pillow 2.4 (https://github.com/python-imaging/Pillow/issues/479)

Answer (score 0):

According to [cgohlke](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21017652/python-pil-image-save-error-in-case-of-eps-format/23597907?noredirect=1#comment36269240_21017652) this was a bug in Pillow and has been fixed in 2.4.0, which was released last month (1st April 2014).

From the [bug report](https://github.com/python-imaging/Pillow/issues/479):

> `io.TextIOWrapper` expects an object with `io.IOBase` interface, not a Python 2 `file` object. Using `fh = io.open('test.eps', 'wb')` passes this stage but `io.TextIOWrapper.write()` expects unicode strings; the example fails with `TypeError: can't write str to text stream`.